# Migration from php 7.4 to 8 (DSO and live flush echo)

Tags: php, flush, php-8

The question is about migration from PHP 7.4 to PHP 8 and what would be the equivalent of DSO for php 8.

I read here https://docs.cpanel.net/ea4/php/php-8/ that PHP 8 and DSO are no longer compatible...

so what is the alternative ?

The way I use DSO : context ob_flush / ob_implicit_flush / each "echo" outputs AND still continues to execute.

example when I try: in a live MEGA long execution of an ajax and live feedback returned to html while being executed

```
<?php 
echo 'hello';
// LONG DB RETRIVAL OR API CALL THAT WAITS SERVER ANSWER....
echo 'called';
// PROCESS STUFF
echo 'done';
?>
```

in this scenario, WHILE the php executes, I see 'hello', few seconds after 'called' appear, etc.

In my DSO setup, the script don't have to wait the full completion before beginning to output.

In PHP 8, how can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

DSO aka Apache mod_php is still available for PHP 8. It's only CPanel that doesn't support it. If you're not using CPanel, you're not affected.

On Ubuntu run the following to install PHP8 as Apache module

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php8.0
```

Comment: I have CPANEL and I just test it and it's working ;) PHP 8.0 ( ea-php80 ) cgi outputs echos while executing